# How to clean stylsheets from Joomla head by using document->_styleSheets =

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Joomla 2.5

as advised we are to use

```
$document   = &JFactory::getDocument()
document->_styleSheets= array();
```

and place it in template before/after the head load to clear any css stylesheets from head , 
this works only for template css files , k2 css files   but nothing else . if you have modules that use stylesheets , even if they used `$document->addStyleSheet(path);` properly the clear will not work for them

I also tested `setHeadData()`  and all possible code that can be "found" ( joomla is bad in docs) and there is no simple way to rebuild the head plus none of them will hold a stylesheets from a module or plugin or any other component but k2.

Does anyone know a proper way to clean the head from all styles or js calls and place your own in there ?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By this way you can only clean styles from components but not from modules or plugins. There is no way at the moment to handle this for all types. The only way is to use "ReReplacer" component to get rid of unwanted scripts or stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the styles in the Template code like you sayed above.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a system plugin.

A few of the available optimisation plugins allow you to remove unwanted scripts and stylesheets from the output.

http://jproven.com/extensions/jbetolo

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jch-optimize/

Answer (score 0):

For anybody searching for this, heres a code that works with Joomla 2.5:

```
$doc= JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->_styleSheets['http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$this->baseurl.'/media/path/to/file.css']);
```